# not . p related filter

Tags: haskell, filter

Hi guys I'm relatively noob with Haskell and still learning, so why does this not work?

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst p xs = delete (not . p) (filter (not . p)  xs)
```

As I get the following error message in my terminal:

```
ERROR "FirstLiterate.lhs":58 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : delete (not . p) (filter (not . p) xs)
*** Term           : not . p
*** Type           : a -> Bool
*** Does not match : a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

So I get it that the type doesn't match the type in my definition. How could I change this so that I don't have to change (a -> Bool)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `filter` will delete all elements that don't satisfy `p`, so it's not clear what you want to delete after that. Do you intend to delete the first element that satisfies some `not . p`?

Comment: I want to delete the first element that does not meet the property p.

Comment: `\p -> uncurry (++) . second (drop 1) . span p`, with `first` from `Control.Arrow`

Comment: @Rhymoid what exactly are you doing there, if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: `filterFirst p xs = tail $ filter (not . p  xs)`

Comment: @MarvinEffing: read from right to left: split the list into two, taking all first elements that match `p` on the left, and the tail on the right; in the second element of the resulting tuple, drop one element from the list (note: this is that first element for which `p` is `False`); concatenate the lists in the tuple to a single list.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I don't recognize those error messages...

Answer (score 6):

The first argument of `delete` should be an element of the list (in this case, a value of type `a`), not a function of type `a -> Bool`.

The type error you got tells you that `not . p` has type `a -> Bool`, but the `delete` function was expecting a value of type `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deleteBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: `deleteBy` can't be used on its own to implement `deleteFirst`, which is what OP wants.

Comment: It can. `deleteBy` works only once, it's *deleteFirstBy* and not a synonym for `filter`. Hint: ignore one of the arguments of the function

Comment: D'oh. Sorry about the -1, apparently I don't know `Data.List` well enough :(

Comment: No problem, I even didn't know `delete` existed somewhere before this question.